# 'Uncaught TypeError' while dynamically creating select options using jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm using jQuery to dynamically set the options available in one select box based on the option selected in another select box. But when I select an option I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '2' in entop_1
```

The number listed in this example error as '2' and variable "entop_1" change based on which option is selected. Any help with this issue would be appreciated.

I'm currently using jQuery 2.0.0 min. The form used is:

```
<form id="addForm">

<!-- Ent Select -->
<select id="ent_id" name="ent_id">
<option value="0">- Select -</option>
<option value="1">Ent 1</option>
<option value="2">Ent 2</option>
<option value="3">Ent 3</option>
</select>

<!-- Cat Select -->
<select id="cat_id" name="cat_id"></select>

</form>
```

And the script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var entop_1 = {"- Select -": "0","Option A": "1","Option B": "2",};
var entop_2 = {"- Select -": "0","Option C": "3","Option D": "4",};
var entop_3 = {"- Select -": "0","Option E": "5","Option F": "6",};
$("#ent_id").change(function()
{
    var $cat_set = $("#cat_id");
    $cat_set.empty(); // remove old options
    var $ent_var = $("#ent_id option:selected").val();

    $.each('entop_' + $ent_var, function(key, value) {
        $cat_set.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", value).text(key));
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Is `'entop_' + $ent_var` supposed to be an element class..? In that case, you're missing an `.` at the beginnig. Otherwise, I'm not sure what you're trying to `$.each()` over..?

Comment: I'm trying to append the options using the arrays 'entop_1', 'entop_2' and 'entop_3'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `eval` for that. This line

```
$.each('entop_' + $ent_var, function(key, value) {
```

must be

```
 $.each(eval('entop_' + $ent_var), function(key, value) {
```

But there are two things wrong with this this approach :

1. [Eval is evil.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)
2. `$.each` must be used only with arrays, not objects. (You'll get a `length is undefined` error)

A better way would be to format your data objects into *one* collection, like this :

```
var keys = {
    1: {
        "- Select -": "0",
        "Option A": "1",
        "Option B": "2",
    },
    2: {
        "- Select -": "0",
        "Option C": "3",
        "Option D": "4",
    },
    3: {
        "- Select -": "0",
        "Option E": "5",
        "Option F": "6",
    }
}
```

Then you could use `for..in`

```
$("#ent_id").change(function () {
    var $cat_set = $("#cat_id");
    $cat_set.empty(); // remove old options
    var $ent_var = $("#ent_id option:selected").val();
    //find the corresponding value in object
    var options = keys[$ent_var];
    //    use for..in, not each
    for (var a in options) {
        $cat_set.append($("<option/>", {
            "text": a,
            "value": options[a]
        }));
    }
});
```

But, beware of the order. sometimes `for..in` will not go through the array in order.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/f6Jps/

Answer (score 0):

If `'entop_' + $ent_var` refers to arrays, you should either `eval` the string, or - if the arrays are located globally - use `window['entop_' + $ent_var]` to get the array off of the global `window` object.

Otherwise, jQuery will just try to iterate the string, i guess.

Here's a snip of you code, modified:

```
$.each(eval('entop_' + $ent_var), function(key, value) {
    $cat_set.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", value).text(key));
});
```

or

```
$.each(window['entop_' + $ent_var], function(key, value) {
    $cat_set.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", value).text(key));
});
```